# restrict download of files using google drive API V3

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to create permissions to each file in a specific folder of my google drive but do not want viewers to be able to download. Can someone help me with this?

I have tried to modify the metadata in different ways but nothing works!!!
can someone write an example on how the metadata should be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) and specify in the request body:

```
{
  "copyRequiresWriterPermission": true
}
```

Comment: Awesome!!! 

I was using "copyRequiresWriterPermission" in "Files.permissions"!!!!

Thank you